# sort data in as alphabet in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting

```
protected List<supplier> GetPartner()
{
    supplierDAL supDAL = new supplierDAL();
    List<supplier> list = supDAL.FindByCondition(c => c.status.Equals(true))
                                .OrderBy(c => c.supplier1)
                                .ToList();
    return list;
}
```

A: a1 a2 a3, B: b1 b2 b3, C: c1 c2 c3

How can I sort data in as alphabet, and data from sql?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. What data do you want to sort?

Comment: May be try sorting by c.supplier1.Name or some string property like that

Answer (score 0):

Your `OrderBy` condition should order your results, are you wanting to group the results too so that results beginning with `A`, `B`, and `C` etc are together?  If so then you can use `GroupBy`, for example:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sourceList = new List<Supplier>()
            {
                new Supplier() {Status = true, Supplier1 = "Z99"},
                new Supplier() {Status = true, Supplier1 = "F32"},
                new Supplier() {Status = false, Supplier1 = "B2"},
                new Supplier() {Status = true, Supplier1 = "C3"},
                new Supplier() {Status = true, Supplier1 = "B1"},
                new Supplier() {Status = true, Supplier1 = "A33"},
                new Supplier() {Status = true, Supplier1 = "A3"},
                new Supplier() {Status = true, Supplier1 = "C1"},
            };

            var list = sourceList.Where(c => c.Status.Equals(true)).OrderBy(c => c.Supplier1).GroupBy(c => c.Supplier1.Substring(0, 1)).ToList();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
   }

    public class Supplier
    {
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public string Supplier1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The above will provide me with a `List` of `Supplier` objects ordered by the `Supplier1` property of `Supplier` and then `grouped` by the `first character;

```
.GroupBy(c => c.Supplier1.Substring(0, 1))
```

Of the `Supplier1` property giving me five elements to my `List`, each of which are ordered too.